# How can I get GCP text-to-speech to ignore part of the text?

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'd like for Google to speak only part of the text. I guess I could do something like this:

```
Part of my text <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="">ignored text</phoneme> rest of my text.
```

But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.